# How to edit XML parameter using Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, context.xml

I'm trying to write a timestamp as a context parameter into my context.xml at that time I execute my Ant script.

I was trying the following:

my context.xml

```
<Parameter name="deployingTimeStamp" 
    value="16.07.2012" <!-- shall be changed! -->
    override="true" />
```

my build.xml

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="time" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
    unit="hour"/>
</tstamp>

<replace file="${conf.dir}/dev/context.xml" >
    <replacefilter token="deployingTimeStamp" value="${time}" />
</replace>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't replace the value, it just replaces the name "deployingTimeStamp" itself and changes it to the current date.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacefilter token is going to replace the token you define.  Why don't you add a placeholder value in the XML (i.e. [[buildTimeStamp]] ) and then use:

```
<replace file="${conf.dir}/dev/context.xml" >
    <replacefilter token="[[buildTimeStamp]]" value="${time}" />
</replace>
```

So your original xml would be

```
<Parameter name="deployingTimeStamp" 
value="[[buildTimeStamp]]" <!-- shall be changed! -->
override="true" />
```

---

**Additional tips based on comment discussion:**

What you might not be doing is copying your main source files into a build directory to perform your replaces first.  This is pretty standard in build scripts which is why I mentioned you check your files out of source control first.  If you are not using source control and have a folder on your computer then you need to copy the files from that folder to another folder first before performing your replace and other packaging of the app.

```
  <copy todir="../dest/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
```

Something like above where you copy source to working directory.  THEN you perform your actions on it, and afterwards remove it when you have a package (i.e. jar file or war file or something if java).  You can view the delete functionality in Ant's documentation as well:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Comment: In our build files we use tokens like @TIMESTAMP@  but you can use any string that might not be duplicated elsewhere.

Comment: yes that would work once - after that, the placeholder is overwritten and next time i will execute my Ant script this placeholder wouldn't exist anymore

Comment: Normally you build from source or version control so you set that parameter in version control and your Ant script checks out code for each build.  We use Hudson (continuous integration) and it checks out code and then executes build scripts but that is the standard practice.

Comment: meaning you also version your build.xml file in the trunk of your source so it gets checked out when you do builds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike but I guess this won't help me solving my problem. What do you mean with Hudson? I don't know that.

Comment: Hudson doesnt matter, it's just a tool that executes your build scripts and monitors your source control.  Whenever you perform a build, you copy your source files to a "working" or "build" directory first, then you perform the filter token replace on that copy, and any other bits like compiling and packaging.  This way next build, when you copy the files again, the context.xml has the placeholder values again.

Comment: See my answer and additional information.  It appears you are not checking out of source control thus your issue of changing value and next build it's the new value.  You need to create a copy of your source files first, then perform changes in build, then delete copy after build.

Comment: Ahh yeah now I got it :) 
I've changed it, now it works fine, thanks a lot Mike!